# Laravel Models - Casting dates to Carbon instances

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

In a Laravel model it is possible to casts fields as Carbon dates like so:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'date_of_birth' => 'date'
    ]
}
```

However this can also be done like so:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    protected $dates= [
        'date_of_birth'
    ]
}
```

What is the difference and what is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in both cases, `Laravel` uses `Model::asDateTime` method. For example, when casting, it uses the following code for dates:

```php
// ...

case 'date':
case 'datetime':
    return $this->asDateTime($value);
```

Also, when getting an attribute from the model, the `Laravel` framework uses something like the following for dates (Model::getAttributeValue):

```php
// ...

// If the attribute is listed as a date, we will convert it to a DateTime
// instance on retrieval, which makes it quite convenient to work with
// date fields without having to create a mutator for each property.
if (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) && ! is_null($value)) {
    return $this->asDateTime($value);
}
```

So, there's no difference. Which way is the appropriate? It depends on your preference, IMO.